# RewriteRule not working when file extensions included

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey, I am trying to use mod_rewrite to make `http://example.com/style/universal.css` show the page `http://example.com/style.php?n=universal`

I am currently using the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^style/([^/\.]+)\.css$ style.php?n=$1
```

But it doesn't seem to work, for some reason it instead shows a `404 Not Found` which is not even the correct 404 page.

I have tried doing it without the extension `.css` (i.e. `http://example.com/style/universal`) with the `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule ^style/([^/\.]+)$ style.php?n=$1
```

Which works, but I would much prefer it if I could get it working with the `.css` extension.

It seems to be something with the server ignoring the RewriteRule if a  file extension is used. Is there a `RewriteCond` or something obvious that I am missing?

**I should also mention that there is a `.htaccess` in the parent directory which is set by  WordPress, the contents of this are:**

```
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Brad.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need the `.css` extension if you make sure to send a `Content-Type: text/css` HTTP header from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your mod_rewrite to log all the steps it does processing your url

```
RewriteLog "/tmp/mysite_rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 6
```

reading the logs you should be able to understand how your url is rewritten and what is the problem.

Comment: I don't own my own server. Is there any other way to debug?